# WPF Style for propery Tag of TextBox

Tags: wpf

How can I set the style for Tag property?
For example Foreground in TextBox I want to set as White and Foreground for Tag as Grey.

```
<TextBox x:Name="MessageText"
         Style="{StaticResource MessageTextBox}"                     
         Tag="Type your message here"
</TextBox>
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are a little bit confused about `Tag` property usage.

From [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag?view=netframework-4.8):

> This property is analogous to Tag properties in other Microsoft
> programming models, such as Visual Basic for Applications or Windows
> Forms. Tag is intended to provide a pre-existing property location
> where you can store some basic custom information about any
> FrameworkElement without requiring you to subclass an element.

It is only a property in which you can store some useful data to associate to you graphic element/control. It has no graphic/style purpose!

Probably you are looking for something like [Watermark](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-add-a-watermark-to-a-textbox?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)